# How to open 2.90(2.80+) blend file in 2.79

Tags: blend-files

I can't find solution how to open .blend file that are 2.80+ version, into 2.79 version.
I tried with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> -> it works only for object, the textures are missing.[image]

Any solutions?

Comment: Have you tried 'appending' the objects? Why 2.79?

Comment: With appending the results is same as the image above. I need 2.79, because there is addons exporter, that doesn't support 2.80+

Comment: In general you can't expect files from newer version to properly open in older versions. Blender provides [backward compatibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_compatibility) but not [forward compatibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_compatibility). In this case there are likely issues with the material and texture setup. You may want to try to change the render engine to Cycles, since Blender Internal doesn't exist in versions past 2.79 thus the file doesn't contain any material definitions for this render engine.

Comment: What exporter? @Rumen

Comment: This exporter: https://sourceforge.net/projects/blenderextrainz/files/BlenderXML%20exporter%20for%20Trainz/x0.96/